# Extend home network via wireless bridge

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, network-printer, bridge

I'm trying to set things up so that devices can print wirelessly from anywhere in the house. However, they seem unable to find the network printer when connected to the downstairs access point. Any suggestions? Thanks!

[image: Network diagram]

Comment: Just use wireless extenders/repeaters. You can daisychain them so your coverage is improved. Network performance might be slightly affected but I don't think it'll be noticed in your scenario.

Comment: @BigChris Thanks Chris, I'm just trying to find a way to do so without purchasing any additional hardware.

Comment: Your picture, is that existing hardware? Or an idea setup?

Comment: @BigChris It's the existing hardware.

Comment: Can devices on your downstairs AP ping your network printer? Do they get Internet? Can they communicate with other machines on the LAN?

Comment: The devices connected to the AP downstairs get internet access. I haven't tried to ping the printer. I ran the default Add new printer utility and it pulled up nothing. If I move the printer to the downstairs network then it detects it just fine.